# Qual o custo de um update quando ele não encontra o registro?

Tags: sql, delphi, if, sql-update

Estou fazendo alguns SQLs em meu programa Delphi e me surgiu essa dúvida, qual o custo para o motor do banco quando um `UPDATE` não encontra o registro conforme os parâmetros do `WHERE`?

Minha pergunta surgiu pela necessidade de fazer alguns `IFs` no programa para verificar antes se um determinado numero satisfaz o UPDATE, vou dar um exemplo:

```
  if (param_pedido > 0){
     update tabela set campo = valor where pedido = param_pedido 
     update ...
     update ...
     update ...
     update ...
  }
```

Se avaliarmos o `IF` não faz muito sentido a menos que o `UPDATE` seja muito custoso para o banco de dados quando ele não encontra o registro em questão.

Não me entendam mal, não é preguiça de digitar, eu tenho uma certa neurose em deixar o código o mais enxuto e limpo possível e dependendo eu teria que fazer um `IF` para cada update.

O que os colegas tem a dizer com respeito a isso?

Answer (score 2):

O custo de um *UPDATE* que não afeta nenhuma linha é o mesmo custo de um *SELECT* com a busca correspondente.

A pesquisa para saber se os registros existem pode fazer sentido em certos casos, por exemplo:

- Se você precisar executar mais lógica além do update;
- Se você precisa fazer um "antes e depois" dos dados, você terá a quantidade de registros a afetar no resultado da pesquisa do antes;
- Até onde lembro o *UPDATE* retorna a quantidade de linhas afetadas. Se você fizer a atualização através de uma biblioteca que o encapsule, mas que não traga essa informação, você vai precisar dela de outra maneira.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Renan, a minha questão é bem simples mesmo, não preciso fazer uso dos dados depois do update é só um update para retirar um numero de pedido de uma renegociação, sei que existe um custo para o UPDATE como você colocou, a questão é deixar esse custo para o banco ou para a aplicação, como é um simples select e esses resultados não vão transitar na rede por se tratar de um UPDATE, creio que o IF neste caso é dispensável, mas posso estar errado por isso levantei a questão.